# Rails rspec view with locale, No route matches

Tags: locale, rspec-rails

This spec passes but fails after introducing locale (the application however works):

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe "products/show" do
  before do
    assign(:product, mock_model("Product", name: "Car", description: "petrol engine"))
  end
  it "renders name" do
    render
    expect(rendered).to match /Car/
  end
end
```

Then I add a scope to the routes to include the locale:
...

```
  scope "/:locale" do
    resources :products
    root :to => 'products#index'
  end
```

...

In application controller I define:

```
def self.default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    I18n.locale = 'en'  # fixed for tests
    { :locale => I18n.locale}
end
```

In the browser the app works again with paths like
/en/product/1   to render the show template

But my test above fails with:

> 1) products/show renders name
>        Failure/Error: render
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products", :locale=>#}
>        # ./app/views/products/show.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_products_show_html_erb__333746538_80999240'
>        # ./spec/views/products/show.html.erb_spec.rb:10:in`block (2 levels) in '

Why does the test fail while the app works?

How do I make it pass?

Comment: It seems that rspec does not honor default_url_options.  See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for me:

copied from https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255 
author: https://github.com/oelmekki

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def url_for_with_locale_fix(options)
    url_for_without_locale_fix({:locale => I18n.default_locale}.merge(options))
  end
  alias_method_chain :url_for, :locale_fix
end
```

Comment: 'rspec spec/views'

works now, but

    'spring rspec spec/views'

doesn't

     ActionView::Template::Error:
       stack level too deep
     # /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23

I got used to test with guard-spring. Now this does not work for views.